# Как преобразовать DataFrame в аудио файл и послушать его?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, аудио, matplotlib

Хочу использовать ряд данных, чтобы получить звуковой файл и послушать его.

Использовала такой шаблон:

```
import numpy as np
import wavio
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

rate = 44100    # samples per second
T = 3           # sample duration (seconds)
f = 440.0       # sound frequency (Hz)

# Compute waveform samples
t = np.linspace(0, T, T*rate, endpoint=False)
x = np.sin(2*np.pi * f * t)

# Write the samples to a file
wavio.write("sine.wav", x, rate, sampwidth=3)

plt.scatter(t, x)
plt.show()
```

Получается, надо заменить частоту на DataFrame, но как сделать это не знаю. Попробовала по разному, не вышло. Тут скорее даже как прописать в `x, rate, sampwidth=3`.

Кто-то знает, что можно сделать?

```
1.11135
1.11126
1.11154
1.11133
1.11153
1.1116
1.11115
1.11089
1.11082
1.11075
1.111
1.11105
1.11091
1.11059
1.11043
1.1107
1.11133
1.11156
1.1112
1.11107
1.11135
1.11142
1.1117
1.11152
1.11148
1.1114
1.1113
1.1112
1.11142
1.11125
1.11076
1.1111
1.11102
1.1108
1.11064
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Тут скорее даже как прописать в "x, rate, sampwidth=3"

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"data": x})

In [61]: df
Out[61]:
            data
0       0.000000
1       0.062648
2       0.125051
3       0.186961
4       0.248138
...          ...
132295 -0.308339
132296 -0.248138
132297 -0.186961
132298 -0.125051
132299 -0.062648

[132300 rows x 1 columns]
```

---

Чтобы записать WAV файл:

```
wavio.write("c:/temp/sine24.wav", df["data"].to_numpy(), rate=rate, sampwidth=3)
```

PS значение `sampwidth`, должно соответствовать длине ряда `data`. Т.е. `len(data)` должен быть приблизительно равным `rate * T`

---

**UPD:** похоже главная сложность, с которой столкнулась автор вопроса, это попытка прослушать WAV файл, который длится `261 / 44100 = 0.00591` секунд. ;)

Comment: а если перевести rate и sample в category? не сильно облегчит?

Comment: @strawdog, посыпаю голову пеплом... ;)

Comment: @Анжелика, у меня созданный файл "c:/temp/sine24.wav" замечательно проигрывается - звучит как монотонный "п-и-и-и-и-п"

Comment: @Анжелика, я понял. Вы создали файл с 261 значением. Для `rate = 44100`, это соответствует `261 / 44100 = 0.00591` секунд звучания ;)